# Why aren't UI components declared as static?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Let's say that my main class is this:

```
public class mainActivity: MonoBehaviour { ... }
```

When I want to initialize an Image for example, I have to declare it as:

```
public Image myImage;
```

Only then I can have access to this instance from Unity's menu. My question is simple. In OOP when we want to access a variable without creating an object we declare it as static. So it becomes class' variable. Right? But Unity lets me create an Image while it's not static and I don't create an object of my class.

How is this possible? Does unity create any "invisible" object of my main class or so?

Comment: When attaching the component to a gameObject, the component is automatically instantiated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily an invisible object. The class in question is serialized into a text-based version of the class in which Unity is able to read/write from the editor. If you open a .Unity scene file in a text editor you will see this serialization in practice.

Comment: My question is: how is possible to access Image 1)without being static or 2) without creating an object of the class

Comment: This is possible through serialization. If you don't know what that is, I suggest you look it up. It's a very powerful technique for creating text representations of a class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems a little weird to me but I'll try to understand it

Comment: That answer is not answering the question. The reason why a reference declaration does not create the object is not related to serialization or the way unity handles scenes yaml file.